# Openocd one-liner for proper multicore MCU reset?

Tags: openocd

I am working with a RP2040 multicore MCU running FreeRTOS SMP; and so far I have used the following one-liner command to restart the code running on the MCU (I use openocd in MINGW64 bash):

```
/c/path/to/openocd/src/openocd.exe -s /c/path/to/openocd/tcl -f interface/picoprobe.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg -c "init ; reset ; exit"
```

A lot of the times this command works for me, but occasionally I've experienced, that when I use certain construct (e.g. timer ISR), and I use this command, something goes wrong - either the timer ISR does not start, or some FreeRTOS task does not start.

I spent quite a bit of time thinking this happens either due to improper coding on my side, or a bug in FreeRTOS - however, I almost by accident noticed, that if instead of the above command, I restart the code in a `gdb` session - which means that in one terminal I have openocd running:

```
/c/path/to/openocd/src/openocd.exe -s /c/path/to/openocd/tcl -f interface/picoprobe.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg
```

... and in another terminal, I have `gdb` running:

```
gdb-multiarch my_progam.elf -ex 'target extended-remote localhost:3333'
```

... and I restart via `r`un command in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: C:\path\to\my_progam\build\my_progam.elf
```

... *then* my code starts running properly, as expected!!

My only guess for this problem is, that when running the one-liner openocd command, access to both cores is probably not "simultaneous" and so there might happen a discrepancy in timing of the startup routine on the MCU; `gdb` on the other hand, when starting up the session, halts both cores, and so (I guess), when doing `r`un, the code is restarted synchronously across both cores, and things work as intended.

So, my question is: is there an `openocd` one-liner command, that would restart the code on the MCU in the same way `r`un in `gdb` does?

Answer (score 0):

( As posted on https://github.com/raspberrypi/openocd/issues/64#issuecomment-1167520811 )

Ok, I think I found it.

Basically, what helped, was to run the openocd command without `-c` commands, and connect to it with `telnet`, instead of `gdb`.

Then, in `telnet`, it is easier to quickly explore the effect of commands, and look up help.

Eventually, I realized that `rp2040.core0 arp_reset assert 1 ; rp2040.core1 arp_reset assert 1` basically halts each core individually - for me, it gives same effect as `reset halt`; then to have the core running again, as with `reset run`, you can issue  `rp2040.core0 arp_reset assert 0 ; rp2040.core1 arp_reset assert 0` - and this gives the same results (that is, sometimes timers/tasks do not run).

Then, since the above debug log mentions each core being targeted separately, I thought: what if, once the cores are halted, we run core 1 first? And indeed, that was the solution:

```
> targets
    TargetName         Type       Endian TapName            State
--  ------------------ ---------- ------ ------------------ ------------
 0* rp2040.core0       cortex_m   little rp2040.core0.cpu   running
 1  rp2040.core1       cortex_m   little rp2040.core1.cpu   running

> rp2040.core0 arp_reset assert 1 ; rp2040.core1 arp_reset assert 1
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x000000ee msp: 0x20041f00
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x000000ee msp: 0x20041f00
> rp2040.core1 arp_reset assert 0 ; rp2040.core0 arp_reset assert 0
```

Note that `arp_reset assert 0` *stops* the reset, that is, allows the cpu core to run; we control which one goes first, here core 1, by calling `rp2040.core1 arp_reset ...` first.

The same result can be obtained with `reset halt` for both cores (instead of halting them individually via `arp_reset assert 1`):

```
> targets
    TargetName         Type       Endian TapName            State
--  ------------------ ---------- ------ ------------------ ------------
 0* rp2040.core0       cortex_m   little rp2040.core0.cpu   running
 1  rp2040.core1       cortex_m   little rp2040.core1.cpu   running

> reset halt
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x000000ee msp: 0x20041f00
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x000000ee msp: 0x20041f00
> targets
    TargetName         Type       Endian TapName            State
--  ------------------ ---------- ------ ------------------ ------------
 0* rp2040.core0       cortex_m   little rp2040.core0.cpu   halted
 1  rp2040.core1       cortex_m   little rp2040.core1.cpu   halted

> rp2040.core1 arp_reset assert 0 ; rp2040.core0 arp_reset assert 0
```

And finally we can put this in a one-liner:

```
/c/path/to/openocd/src/openocd.exe -s /c/path/to/openocd/tcl -f interface/picoprobe.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg -c "init ; reset halt ; rp2040.core1 arp_reset assert 0 ; rp2040.core0 arp_reset assert 0 ; exit"
```

The above command works for me (all timers and FreeRTOS tasks are running when I restart the code using that command) ...